# How to go about implementing a parallelized Dijkstra's algorithm using OpenMP/MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement a parallelized version of Dijkstra's algorithm (my very first parallel algorithm) for a course project. I got the sequential part down using a priority queue with no problem, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about designing a parallel version. I've been using [this](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node35.html) as a reference so far. I'm not asking anyone to design the whole thing for me, just offer me some insights or good advice about how to go about the implementation. I've been considering these things so far:

- OpenMP, MPI or both?
- PCAM? (e.g. graph partitioning)
- Shared memory?

Comment: GIYF: Try this for ideas: http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/miller/Courses/CSE633/Ye-Fall-2012-CSE633.pdf

Comment: I searched for a long time on Google, and I have no idea how I missed this. Thanks!

Comment: @Ira post this as an answer please.

Comment: @NordCoder: you may want to answer your own question with details on what you did, just to get its status updated as *answered*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this presentation for ideas:

http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/miller/Courses/CSE633/Ye-Fall-2012-CSE633.pdf